# powershell: Parsing to function

Tags: powershell

In short:
At all our customers we have computers with some specific features.  Last octet always have the same value in their existing IP Range.  Per customer the hostname is different but unique. All endpoints should get these hostnames in their registry where Custom1 is for featureA and Custom2 is for featureB.

So, in my script I have gathered their IPrange, so I have the IP Addresses for each feature as the last octet for all customers are the seame for every feature-Computer. Using this info I gather their hostnames.  This works like a charm, so far so good.

Now I call the the Function [Add2Reg] (what is in a name) as follows:

```
Add2Reg -FeatureType "NN" -CustomNField "1" -RegValue "$NNHostName"
```

OR

```
Add2Reg -FeatureType "DS" -CustomNField "2" -RegValue "$DSHostName"
```

Or.. whatever feature we need to define

I start the function with

```
param (
 [String]$FeatureType, 
 [String]$CustomNField, 
 [String]$RegValue
)
$CustomField = "Custom"+$CustomNField  # in this case creates "Custom1"
$Hostname = $RegValue  # Old code is using $Regvalue, kept it as lazy
$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MyCompany"
$FeatureType = ...  #needed for someting else...
...
```

The actual registry command:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath `
    -Name $CustomField `
    -Value $Hostname `
    -PropertyType ExpandString `
    -Force
```

In between I have several Write-Host lines for checking during building this, and I always see the correct values.
Running this I get following output:

```
Custom1      : MCNN01
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE
PSChildName  : MyCompany
PSDrive      : HKLM
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

No error, warning or what so ever. But when I look into the registry, none is added...  It must be something simple or stupid basic that i am not aware of and need to be told of...

Thx in advance!

Comment: Are you running this script from an elevated PowerShell session?

Comment: Yes, "Administrator: " is in ISE.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The return would be `New-ItemProperty : Requested registry access is not allowed.` if not elevated. That return says that it was written to the registry. How are you looking at if it was written? If it's regedit are you refreshing the view after completion, because it should be there. What's the output of `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\MyCompany` after running that?

Comment: @BenH - I've had registry-based stuff fail silently when not run elevated; I've also had registry-based stuff give completely misleading errors. I never take elevation for granted when the registry is involved; I will always ask if it's not specified.

Comment: Another thought are you running it 32 bit PowerShell and it's being written to `WOW3264Node`?

Comment: @BenH - Get-Item... no result and No, it is not in WOW...

Comment: @All - Issue solved. We learned this is a not-very-well-documented "Feature-By-Design" with the management software we use.  The CustomX fields are transferred to the SaaS solution and then removed from the local registry and that happens withing a second.  The scripts we want to use these data in are filled with the values by the management software/agent.  So, all is working correctly, only not as expected.  Thx all for your input!